# Joining columns for today and yesterday in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a mySQL database:

Prices:

```
Date         Security   Price
2017-06-06   A          3.1
2017-06-06   B          4.1
2017-06-06   C          5.1
2017-06-05   A          3
2017-06-05   B          4
2017-06-05   C          5
... more prices
```

Trades:

```
Date         Security   Description
2017-06-06   A          adesc
2017-06-06   B          bdesc
2017-06-06   C          cdesc
... more trades
```

I will like to **create a view** which adds 2 more columns to the current `Trades` table, based on today's date and the date before. For example, if today's date was `2017-06-06`, then the output I'm looking for will be:

Trades:

```
Date         Security   Description   Price(Today)  Price(Yesterday)
2017-06-06   A          adesc         3.1           3
2017-06-06   B          bdesc         4.1           4
2017-06-06   C          cdesc         5.1           5
... more trades
```

I know that I can do a left join based on the date to get one of the columns (ie `SELECT * FROM Trades LEFT JOIN Prices ON Prices.Date=DATE(NOW())`, but is it possible to extend the syntax to allow for multple columns to be added as shown in the example?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes. Another LEFT JOIN is all that you need

Comment: Hi @Strawberry, I forgot to mention, but I was getting a `Not unique table/alias` error when I tried to do that

Comment: Give each instance a different alias: `LEFT JOIN my_table AS yesterday`

Comment: @Strawberry Yes adding an alias like in Mike's answer solved the issue I had!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, give this a try:

```
LEFT JOIN Prices AS TodaysPrices ON Prices.Date=CURDATE()
LEFT JOIN Prices AS YesterdaysPrices ON Prices.Date=SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!